# YouTube video player integration

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-api

Video becomes unwatchable after 3 seconds of playing.
like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzz2y.png)

I've used this library youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.1

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.